# In the following geometry figure with a circle and triangle, find the measure of the largest side length

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

As title suggests, the question is to find the largest length's measure (the blue length) in the figure below. Note that the blue length is NOT passing through the center of the circle and the orange length is tangent to the circle. I tried several different approaches to this problem, both purely geometric and trigonometric, but none of them provided a simple solution until I recalled an important theorem. Please post your own solutions as well, I will have mine as an answer below!

[image]

Comment: @Vasili That's incorrect. The orange line IS tangent but the blue line is NOT passing through the center of the circle. Furthermore the orange line being tangent does not form a 3-4-5 triangle anywhere. Please observe the question more carefully

Comment: Is it a puzzle you set up? Is it from any book? What are some calculations you started with?

Comment: @Narasimham It comes from a friend of mine who runs a mathemstics page on Instagram. As for my solution, I have posted it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangle cosine Rule applied twice, alternate segment angle, outside tangent squared is product segment theorem are used

I quickly got two  results by above *trig numerical method.* It is only *slightly different from* the first one by @Goku. Others complex, discarded. Can you spot my mistake in the second solution on `Mathematica` ? Or, is a second solution also admissible?

Two values of long side $ BC= x+y ~$ are

$$(1.5+4.5, 1.50735+4.46341=6, 5.97076)$$

[image]

$ (x,y)$ are segments in the blue line outside  and inside respectively.

$$ ( x^2=3^2+2^2-2\cdot 3 \cdot 2~\cos \beta,~y^2+4^2-2 \cdot 4 y ~\cos \beta = 2^2,~ x*(x+y)=9 ~)$$

[image]

Comment: Your calculations check out. After solving for $x$ and $y$, I got the right answer. Where did you encounter a problem?

Comment: This points to another solution involving different circum-radii.

Comment: @Narasimham: The other solution isn't a CAS accuracy problem. Your eqns yield an exact polynomial $(2x-3)(x^4-22x^2-24x+81)=0$; your other $x$ is not some "inaccurate" duplicate of $3/2$, it's just-plain *extraneous*. The corresponding triangles don't fit together properly. You can verify that [Stewart's Thm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) isn't satisfied by those values. (Or, calculate the cosines of the two angles made by the green segment and the blues; they aren't mutual negatives, so the angles aren't supplements.) ... Interesting that it's such a *near miss*, however.

Comment: Or a shadow spurious solution. Noted this phenomenon  for several combination of 3 radial lines.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is pretty forward:

[image]

We can label the triangle as $\triangle ABC$ with $D$ on $BC$. Since we know that $AB$ is tangent to the circle, we can use the [Alternate Segment Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/) and say that $\angle BAD=\angle BCA=\alpha$. Next we can label $\angle ABC=\beta$.

Now, notice that $\triangle BAD$ and $\triangle BCA$ are similar via the AAA property, thus the relation:

$$\frac{2}{4}=\frac{3}{BC}$$
$$BC=6$$.

Comment: Did you mean $\triangle BAD$ and $\triangle BCA$ are similar via the AAA property?

Comment: Well yes, they are in fact similar @Narasimham

Comment: I've fixed it now. Thank you @nickgard