# Two configurations around same radial line lengths in a triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

OA is a fixed line length $a$. A circle is drawn tangent at O. A transversal through A cuts the circle at B and C. The radial segment are lengths $(b,c)$.

[image]

It is known $ AC=\dfrac{a c}{b} $ by virtue of similar triangles $(OBC,AOC).$

Motivation of the question is a calculation using Cosine Rules etc. suggesting different length combinations of [AB & BC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581969/in-the-following-geometry-figure-with-a-circle-and-triangle-find-the-measure-of).

EDIT1:

This in hindsight appears to be an accuracy problem of CAS that was not expected at start.

Please help finding circumradius in terms of $(a,b,c)$ and angles $(\beta, \gamma)$ between them.

Comment: I see that this is closely related to the problem I posted yesterday. I want to ask, why exactly are you trying to solve for the radius of that circle? It has nothing to do with the problem or the answer that you posted to that original problem

Comment: Since there is another possible combination for $(x,y),$ another connected circum-circle may exist. So would it not be better to ask in a separate related question? I wish to draw and see separate circum-radii if possible in a single sketch to confirm this or otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the circumradius $R$ is unique (if $a,b,c$ allow such a circle to exist).

Choose a coordinate system where $O$ is origin and $A,B,C$ are located at $(a,0)$, $(b\cos\beta,b\sin\beta)$ and $(c\cos\gamma,c\sin\gamma)$ respectively. We will assume $0 < \beta < \gamma \le \frac{\pi}{2}$, this will force $c > b$.

Perform a circle inversion with respect to the unit circle, $A,B,C$ get mapped to
$$A' = \left(\frac1a,0\right),\quad B' = \left(\frac1b\cos\beta,\frac1b\sin\beta\right),\quad C'= \left(\frac1c\cos\gamma,\frac1c\sin\gamma\right)$$
Let $d = 2R$. Since $B,C$ lies on a circle tangent to $OA$ at  $O$. $B', C'$ lie on the line $y = \frac1d$. This implies
$$B' = \left(\sqrt{\frac1{b^2}-\frac1{d^2}}, \frac1d\right)\quad\text{ and }\quad C' = \left(\sqrt{\frac1{c^2}-\frac1{d^2}}, \frac1d\right)$$

Since $A,B,C$ lie on a line, $A',B',C'$ lie on a circle passing through $O$.
Notice $OA' \parallel B'C'$, $OA'$ and $B'C'$ is sharing a common perpendicular bisector. Furthermore, $A'B'$ is mirror image of $OC'$ with respect to this perpendicular bisector. As a consequence, the $x$-coordinates of midpoints of $B'C'$ equals to that of $OA'$. This means
$$\sqrt{\frac1{b^2}-\frac1{d^2}} + \sqrt{\frac1{c^2}-\frac1{d^2}} = \frac1a\tag{*1}$$
As a function of $d$, RHS$(*1)$ isn't real unless $d \ge c = \max(b,c)$.

For $d \in [c,\infty)$, RHS$(*1)$ is strictly increasing and taking values from $\left[\sqrt{\frac1{b^2}-\frac1{c^2}}, \frac1b+\frac1c\right)$.

This means the given geometric configuration is feasible only when
$$\sqrt{\frac1{b^2}-\frac1{c^2}} \le \frac1a < \frac1b + \frac1c$$ and when $a,b,c$ allow such a configuration, the corresponding $d$ and hence $R$ is unique.
With help of a CAS, one find when $R$ exists, it will equal to

$$R = \frac{1}{a\sqrt{\left(\frac1{a^2} + \frac1{b^2} + \frac1{c^2}\right)^2 - 2\left(\frac1{a^4} + \frac1{b^4} + \frac1{c^4}\right)}}$$

Comment: Thanks. So do we have the same circumradii  in the two cases $ BC=(6, 5.97076) ?$ There may be an extraneous circumradius $R~ !$

Comment: As far as I can see, the only way to get more solution is drop the constraint $\gamma \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. If $\gamma > \frac{\pi}{2}$ while keeping $c >b$. The equation becomes $\sqrt{\frac1{b^2} - \frac1{d^2}} \color{red}{-} \sqrt{\frac1{c^2} - \frac1{d^2}} = \frac1a$. Solution exists only when $\frac1b - \frac1c < \frac1a \le \sqrt{\frac1{b^2} - \frac1{c^2}}$ but $R$ is still given by same expression. So $R$ is again unique (if exists)